# What is the minimum pressure of a purely CO₂ atmosphere on Europa that can retain enough heat for surface liquid water?

Tags: atmosphere, planetary-science, water, jupiter, europa

*Ignoring external factors such as Jupiter's magnetosphere blowing this new atmosphere off.
I'm not sure where to begin the maths for that

Comment: For surface liquid water you need not only a temperature above 0.01 °C, you also need a surface pressure of more than 0.006 bar. But the surface pressure of Europa is much lower, about 100 nPa or 1 pbar (yes 1 picobar).

Comment: @Uwe my engineering final project in uni was a Europa lander (DORRA the Europa Explorer, the paper is out in the wild) and every time someone said Europa has an atmosphere I reminded them that there's more atmosphere in a light bulb

Comment: @ErinAnne An Ultra High Vacuum (UHV) with 1 µbar is ten times the surface pressure of Europa.

Answer (score 4):

A very rough starting point is how much this atmosphere would differ from a perfect [blackbody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body).

The melting point of water is roughly 270 kelvin for a wide range of pressures, so with that as a surface temperature, an object would radiate [300 W/m^2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28270+kelvin%29%5E4+*+stefan-boltzman+constant)

Compare that to the solar energy flux of [50 W/m^2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solar+constant+*+%28earth+semi-major+axis+%2F+jupiter+semi-major+axis%29%5E2), and keeping in mind that the cross section area of a sphere receiving light is four times smaller than the total surface area, that means the atmosphere must reduce the thermal radiation to 1/24th of a blackbody.

For comparison, for well insulated Venus, the same numbers are [2600 W/m^2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28venus%20surface%20temperature%29%5E4%20*%20stefan-boltzman%20constant)
emitted and [2600  W/m^2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solar%20constant%20*%20%28earth%20semi-major%20axis%20%2F%20venus%20semi-major%20axis%29%5E2) received for a blackbody with the same temperature. Factoring in the area difference again, the heavy atmosphere of Venus is only improving upon a blackbody by a factor of 4. (The equality of the two numbers is a coincidence).

So probably we need a stronger greenhouse effect than Venus, but I stress that this is only a very approximate estimate.